# Reactive forms two way binding [Angular2]

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have form like this:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private bankService: BankService) {
        this.page = 1;

        this.filter = this.fb.group({
            text: ['', []],
            bankC: ['', []]
        });
}
```

And from component I need to change `bankC` value. It should work somethig like this:

```
 submitCountry(country) {
        this.filter.value.bankC = country;
    }
```

after `submitCountry` function is called it should update this input in template:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Bank country" formControlName="bankC" />
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You need to update the value on form controls and not the `FormGroup`. See this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html, this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html and this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: Also `setValue()` method (eg. `this.filter.bankC.setValue()`: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#setValue-anchor

Comment: Yep, this is for single value `this.filter.patchValue({'bankC': country});`

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It's ok now, few min before your answer I found solution....